# How to pass parameter to swift class from react native bridge

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

I have a react native app and I call a swift class from this app. I use a bridge for that and 
I want to pass a parameter to init of my Counter class. How can I do that? I am very new on swift and react.

```
@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(Counter, NSObject)
```

swift version is 5.0 react native version is 0.62.1

Comment: Please share more code.

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass params from js to instantiate your native module since RN creates singleton instances for every bridge with default initializer `init`. But you can set needed properties with a function e.g.

MyModuleExport.m:

```
@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(MyModule, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(construct:(NSString*)name value:(NSInteger)value)

@end
```

MyModule.swift:

```
@objc(MyModule)    
class MyModule: NSObject {
    var name: String!
    var value: Int!

    @objc
    func construct(_ name: String, value: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    }
```

JS:

```
const module = NativeModules.MyModule
module.construct("Hello", 100);
```